# Power BI account issue

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Am unable to login to  power bi account.

When I have switched on to "New look on" option am getting below error page.

[image]

[image: Error Page]

Comment: actually I just tried that in my PowerBI env and it did worked fine for me without any issue. May be because you do not have permission, As clearly view error says you do not have access.

Comment: But it does not tell what permission do I need, besides am using Pro trail and it should  have all the privileges as per my assumption.

Comment: are you an admin or did you created this report?
also can you try in some other browser?